# Is there any shorter method to complete the proof?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> If $p^2=a^2\cos^2(\theta)+b^2\sin^2(\theta)$, prove that
>   $$p+\frac{d^2p}{d{\theta}^2}=\frac{a^2b^2}{p^3}$$

I've tried differentiating the given equation $p^2=a^2\cos^2(\theta)+b^2\sin^2(\theta)$ w.r.t $\theta$ to find $\frac{dp}{d\theta}$ and $\frac{d^2p}{d\theta^2}$. However, the direct method seems to lengthy. Is there any shorter method to complete the proof?

Comment: You could try rewriting $p^2=a^2+(b^2-a^2)\sin^2(\theta)$ so you only have just the sin (rather than sin and cos) to differentiate.

Comment: @GeorgeLaw I've converted both the sine and cosine squares to $\cos(2\theta)$ form. But even then it is too huge by hand.

Comment: differentiate given $p^2$ get $2pp'=(b^2-a^2)sin2\theta$ and $2p'p'+2pp''=2(b^2-a^2)cos2\theta$ express $p''(p,a,b,\theta)$ from these two equations then check your OP

Answer (score 1):

Let $p=f(a\cos(\theta),b\sin(\theta))$ where $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$ Then from chain rule $$\frac{d^{2}p}{d\theta^2}=\frac{x}{p}\frac{d^{2}x}{{d\theta}^2}+\frac{y^2}{p^3}\Big(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\Big)^2-\frac{2xy}{p^3}\Big(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\Big)\Big(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\Big)+\frac{y}{p}\frac{d^{2}y}{{d\theta}^2}+\frac{x^2}{p^3}\Big(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\Big)^2.$$ Replace $x=a\cos(\theta)$ and $y=b\sin(\theta),$ then simplify to get the result. Comes right out.

Comment: You could also write this as $\frac{d^{2}p}{d\theta^2}=\frac{1}{p}\Big(x\frac{d^{2}x}{d\theta^2}+y\frac{d^{2}y}{d\theta^2}\Big)+\frac{1}{p^3}\Big(x\frac{dy}{d\theta}-y\frac{dx}{d\theta}\Big)^{2}$ where $x=a\cos(\theta)$ and $y=b\sin(\theta)$ to minimize the amount of algebra.